# Read-only information passing using localStorage with Javascript (not embedded in Hml)

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have been stuck with this thing, any help will be highly appreciated.
I want to pass a value from one HTML page to another HTML page using localStorage by the press of a submit button, here's the value from the first page

#### Reference number : TECS5

And the value has to remain read-only when it appears on the second page.
Also, I can't use any functions like JQuery etc, and the Javascript should be a separate file. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a little bit of code to demonstrate a possible solution. Using the following functions, we can enter a reference number into a form and have it appear on another page.

[image: Enter reference number]

Instead of using JQuery, we'll use the JavaScript function getElementById(). The rest of the code is pretty self-explanatory. Let me know if you have any questions!

page1.html

```
<script src="saveToLocalStorage.js"></script>

<form onsubmit="return saveToLocalStorage()">
Enter reference number: <input id="reference" type="text">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

page2.html

```
<div>Reference number : <span id="place"></span></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
// if you also want this JavaScript in a separate file, we can put it in a function
document.getElementById('place').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("refNum");
</script>
```

saveToLocalStorage.js

```
function saveToLocalStorage() {
    var input = document.getElementById("reference");
    localStorage.setItem("refNum", input.value);
    window.location = "page2.html";
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks works good, only one more thing is needed when the onsubmit on page 1 is pressed the data is stored in local storage, but can also the page 2 be opened using the same button? as doing that will complete the functionality. Cheers

Comment: Great, I updated the code to reflect this extra criteria. Can you also update your question? 

Notice that we have to return the function in the "onsubmit" call and return false from our saveToLocalStorage function. This prevents the page from refreshing.

Can you also tag the answer as correct?

Comment: Well works perfect, thanks again! One last tiny doubt, how can I make a single js file for the complete function?, I mean I want to add the line document.getElementById('place').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("refNum"); in the saveToLocalStorage.js file, which passes the value from the js file to the next page2.html, and sorry for the late response which is maybe due to different time zones. Cheers.

Comment: And can we also implement the whole functionality without using the event registration (onsubmit function) embedded in the HTML please?